# How to add active class in django?

Tags: python, django, web

I have a sidebar where there are links to some pages that have active class if url matches to name of link. But there are also links to pages that I add with for loop in my template. I need to somehow add active class when they are opened. I use `id` to link them.

`template:`

```
{% for branch in branches %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'manager-branch-workers' branch.id %}">{{branch.name}}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

`urls.py:`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('workers/<int:pk>/', views.BranchWorkerList, name='manager-branch-workers')
]
```

Can I compare id and url path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two options available to you:

##### Option 1:

Pass the value of pk as part of your template context and access that value in the template:

```py
class BranchWorkerView(View):
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        context = {
            "pk": pk,
        }
        return render(request, "template_name.html", context)
```

```html
{% for branch in branches %}
    <li>
        <a
            href="{% url 'manager-branch-workers' branch.id %}"
            {% if pk == branch.id and request.resolver_match.url_name == "manager-branch-workers" %}
            class="active"
            {% endif %}>
            {{branch.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

##### Option 2:

Access the pk value directly from the path in your template:

```html
{% for branch in branches %}
    <li>
        <a
            href="{% url 'manager-branch-workers' branch.id %}"
            {% if request.resolver_match.kwargs.pk == branch.id and request.resolver_match.url_name == "manager-branch-workers" %}
            class="active"
            {% endif %}>
            {{branch.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

In both cases, you'll need to access some data from the request object by making use of the `resolver_match` attribute within the template itself. See the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match).